# Python list slices

Tags: tables, lists, columns, python

I'd like to typeset something like this

```
0   1   2   3   4   5 ...
+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o  ...
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

to show slicing in Python lists.

Well, this \tt solution works !

I looked at the  [bytefield](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bytefield/bytefield.pdf) package but I didn't see how to have the indices put at column separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\lapbox` to move the bitheaders:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\centerbitheader}[1]{%
  \lapbox{-.5\bf@bitwidth}{#1}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{bytefield}{6}
      \bitheader[bitformatting={\tiny\centerbitheader}]{0-5} \\
          \bitboxes{1}{HELLO}
       \end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]